# Google Cloud Platform - Application suddenly start charging billing hours?

Tags: google, cloud-hosting, google-app-engine

I have several Java applications running on Google Cloud Platform. There is a free quota of 28 frontend instance hours a day. I have a cron job running every 5 minutes to keep one instance running all the time. So there should be 24 instance hours every day. 
These applications are all running for months already at zero costs. Since a couple of days they seem to charge some frontend hours. E.g.:

```
Mar 1 – 11, 2017:  App Engine Frontend Instances: 265.907 Hours -> $6.08
```

The applications are not even used actually. The usage chart also shows constantly one instance running. Has anybody any idea what that could be about? Did I miss any change from google?

**Edit:**

I guess they currently have a bug in their billing calculation:

https://status.cloud.google.com/

> Since Thursday, 2017-03-09 13:00 US/Pacific, some customers using the free trial for cloud platform services may notice billing charges on their account. These charges are erroneous. No action is required on your side. We'll proactively reimburse you for any payments made.

Comment: Likely because you are using other instances that are paused and they are using resources `Your instances are not charged for per-minute usage charges in TERMINATED state but any resources attached to the virtual machine will be charged until they are deleted, such as static IPs and persistent disks.` or your gone over your trial `12 months have elapsed or you've spent the $300 in credit`

Comment: I guess they currently have a bug in their billing calculation -> See https://status.cloud.google.com/